# AsyncTask Class Runtime Error : concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i m new in android and trying to make simple program that can print variable in **AsyncTask  Class** 
here is my code

```
    int a,b,c;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
a =10;
b=10;
c=a+b;
Context ctx = null;
show(c, ctx );


return null;

}
public  void show(int c2 ,Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(c, "AsyncTask classs + c2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

after running this program , i m getting run time Error

here us LogCat file view

```
  Process: com.example.asycclass, PID: 2539
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
    at com.example.asycclass.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.show(MainActivity.java:74)
    at com.example.asycclass.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
    at com.example.asycclass.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: you are passing a null context to the show method

Comment: @Pramod Yadav then what should i pass? any solution will help me to make my project complete thanks

Comment: your asynctask is inner class of an activity or a separate class

Comment: class asynctask  is inner class of MainActivity

Comment: then use show(c,MainActivity.this); insted of show(c, ctx );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your show Toast code inside runOnUiThread like :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       show(c, ctx );
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana thanks it help me, it save me Time! can u please tell me what is doig this function  `runOnUiThread` ?
i m making web based program in which i need help.

Comment: @AshuKumar,doInBackground is run on outside UI thread so if you wan to do some UI therad task like show message then you can do with runOnUiThread.

Comment: @  Haresh Chhelana  i got it , now i m going ahead with code  what if i have to do any web based code should i do as you mentioned above ?

Comment: i will read it definitely , i m trying from  3 days to load new layout in AsyncTask class ,  can u please tell me how to load new android layout in `AsyncTask` class ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that you're trying to create a `Toast` not from the main thread.
You must create a `handler` and `Runnable` for that and use `handler.post()`

For example

```
Runnable showToast = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Create your Toast here or whatever you want
    }
}
```